# Sybase how to logging changes in views, procedures

Tags: logging, sybase

Is it possible to log deletion of triggers, changes to views, procedures using sp_audit?

Comment: In fact, I do not need to log detailed changes, I just need the dates of these changes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running `(Sybase)SAP ASE`, `sp_audit` **can** audit DDL changes; from the reference manual re: [sp_audit / options](https://help.sap.com/viewer/29a04b8081884fb5b715fe4aa1ab4ad2/16.0.4.0/en-US/a9518f11bc2b1014bd57d46b8704545b.html):

> create
>
> create database, create default,create function, create index, create
> procedure, create role, create rule, create service, create table,
> create trigger, create view, sp_addmessage

and

> drop
>
> drop database, drop default, drop function, drop index, drop
> procedure, drop role, drop rule, drop service, drop table, drop
> trigger, drop view, sp_dropmessage

**NOTES:**

- I'm assuming the `create` option encompasses the (newer) `create or replace ...` commands
- I haven't used `sp_audit` in quite awhile so not sure what the history is with auditing of DDL commands (eg, has DDL auditing always been supported or was it introduced with a particular version of `ASE`)